# Limiting the Upload Location for assets in a Matrix Block

Tags: templating, assets, matrix, dashboard

In the Dashboard, while editing the settings of a Matrix Block — the instructions for setting Upload Location for an Assets field says `Note that the subfolder path can contain variables like {owner.slug} or {owner.author.username}.`

To what does `owner` refer?

Ideally I want to store these assets in Site Assets/pages/{slug of the page this block is on}  — is `owner` the page name or the username or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`owner` is the element which contains your Matrix field.

For example, if you attach a Matrix field to a Section, the `owner` would be **the specific Entry in that Section**.

- `{owner.slug}` - The slug of your entry.
- `{owner.author.username}` - The username of the person who created the entry.